Use of magic matplotlib function in latest jupyter notebook
Recently, I had to upgrade my Jupyter Notebook and Python. After upgrading I encounter an issue with using built-in magic functions such as %matplotlib notebook or %matplotlib inline. At this moment I tried to downgrade it and use the older jupyter version but it does not help.
Do we have any solutions for this?
My Jupyter version is 7.1.3
Pyhton - 3.11.7
Error while viewing a graph.

One I can help with right out of the gate. %matplotlib notebook isn't for current JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook 7+. Jupyter Notebook 7+ uses a lot of the same tech as JupyterLab and so you want to look for things that work with that. In place of %matplotlib notebook with current JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook 7+, you generally want to install and use ipympl. Note that you have to install it. Very important. Then %matplotlib ipympl will work. See documentation here where it says, ...

  "To activate the ipympl backend all you need to do is include the %matplotlib ipympl magic in the notebook."

That covers the %matplotlib notebook; however, what are you seeing when you run %matplotlib inline? That should still work.

Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: ipympl. Using qt instead.
Got this error when tried to import ipympl.

You need to restart things. It isn't going to work on the fly. It changes a lot of things and has to be propagated to a lot of levels. Did you restart the kernel? You may want to try restarting everything.

When i tried to run %matplotlib notebook I am getting this error Javascript Error: IPython is not defined

I just explained in two places on this page that you can no longer use %matplotlib notebook with current JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook 7+. You'd need NbClassic to continue using that.

Yes I did, I did restart the Kernel and cleared all outputs.

It seems it works when I try to clean my browser Cache. After that, it worked. Thanks for the help.
%matplotlib ipympl works fine after clearing out the browser cache.

Is %matplotlib inline still working now?

for version 7+ it doesn't but for version 6.0 its still working

If I explicitly define it, then it throws me a Javascript error or does not show any figures after running a command.

Hmmm... I am using %matplotlib with Jupyter Notebook Version: 7.1.3 and not seeing this. I can share that with you. Go here and click the launch badge to the right of Jupyter Notebook 7+. In the notebook that will come up try adding %matplotlib inline to the top example there. If that works, then you can post in your example code and try. All my simple matplotlib examples tha tI pasted in worked with it just fine, too.

You seemed to not want to restart everything. Have you tried that in this case?

In place of %matplotlib notebook, with current JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook 7+, you generally want to install and use ipympl. Note that you have to first install ipympl in your environment. This is very important. Restart everything, too. Restarting the kernel only is insufficient. (OP says clearing cache of browser helped. I've seen refreshing the browser Jupyter page sometimes be enough; however, honestly restarting machine or at least Jupyter and the browser is advised.)
Then following successful installation and refresh, %matplotlib ipympl will work much like %matplotlib notebook did with the older tech. See documentation here where it says:

"To activate the ipympl backend all you need to do is include the %matplotlib ipympl magic in the notebook."

%matplotlib notebook isn't for current JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook 7+. Jupyter Notebook 7+ uses a lot of the same tech as JupyterLab, and so you want to look for things that work with that.
Finally, if you prefer the older way with %matplotlib notebook, you can continue to use NbClassic at this time, see here.
